# chrome dev tools crashed during initialization call

Tags: javascript, html, jsonp, iife

The code below crashed on this line, `document.body.appendChild(script);`, where the new script gets added to the body element.The page crashed and browser's debugger tool showed this message `DevTools was disconnected from the page. Once page is reloaded, DevTools will automatically reconnect`. I'm not sure what is the error that caused the debugger tool to crash since the same process of adding and removing script to get random quote worked with `#btn-quote` click event. I've also tried to have the init function call when the page is loaded by replacing `appController.init();` with `window.onload = init;`, but the same error still occurred. I would really appreciate with anyone can point out any logical error I made in the code below as I'm not able to figure them out.

```
var dataController = (function() {
    var data = {
        quote: '',
        author: ''
    }
    function setRandomQuote() {
        var script = document.createElement('script'); 
        script.src = 'http://api.forismatic.com/api/1.0/?method=getQuote&lang=en&format=jsonp&jsonp=parseQuote'; 
        document.body.appendChild(script);

        window.parseQuote= function(json) {
            data.quote = json.quoteText;
            data.author = json.quoteAuthor;
        }
        script.parentNode.removeChild(script);
    }
    return {
        getQuote: function() {
            setRandomQuote();
            return data;
        }
    };
})();


var UIController = (function(){

    return {
        changeQuote: function(data) {
            document.querySelector('q').innerHTML = data.quote;
            document.querySelector('cite').innerHTML = data.author;
        }
    }
})();


var appController = (function(dataCtrl, UICtrl) {
    var setupEventListener = function() {
        document.querySelector('#btn-quote').addEventListener('click', getRandomQuote);
    };

    function getRandomQuote() {
        var data= {};
        // 1. get quote
        var data = dataCtrl.getQuote();


        // 2. change UI with new quote
       UICtrl.changeQuote(data);
    }

    return {
        init: function() {
            setupEventListener();
            getRandomQuote();
        }
    }

})(dataController, UIController); 


appController.init();
```

Comment: I think you should assign `window.parseQuote` before you append the script node. Not sure if that's related to the problem, though.

Comment: I don't think that is related to the problem. I'm not sure what logical error is here as it worked when clicking the button to get the random quote but not for initializing the page with a random quote.

Comment: I can't reproduce the error in jsfiddle. However, there's a bug in the code. `parseQuote` is called asynchronously, so you're displaying the result of the *previous* call.

Comment: You should call `UIController.changeQuote()` from `parseQuote()`.

Comment: And why do you keep assigning `window.parseQuote()` every time `setRandomQuote()` is called, just do it once at startup.

Comment: Here's the fiddle that demonstrates that there's no crash: https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/yLaa5h8s/12/

Comment: I mean it is not really crashing if I run it without debugging, but the quote string is empty. what crashing is the browser debugger when I tried to run throw to check why the page doesn't initialize with a random quote

Comment: I had the console open and I never saw any problems there.

Comment: The reason it doesn't initialize with the random quote is what I said above. When it calls `getRandomQuote()` during initialization it displays the previous quote, which is the initial empty string.